# How to change column from 'true' to 'false' with condition Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have table with columns:
-id -status -overdue_status -return_time

Default for -overdue_status column is 'false'. I want to make condition where if current time is smaller than 'return_time' column data, set it to 'true'. How to do that? Using mutators, accessors, events and listeners? How?

Comment: I would use a job for that, to update every day the overdue status. Or you can remove overdue status from the database and use an accessor instead, to check return_time against  the current time and date

Comment: How to write that accessor?

Comment: You could define an accessor like so : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define an accessor to calculate the overdue status by comparing to the current date and time :

```php
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
     */
    protected function overdueStatus(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn () => {
                // return_time needs to be cast to a carbon date
                // by doing : protected $dates = ['return_time']; in the model
                return $this->return_time->lessThan(now());
            }
        );
    }
```

You will be able to access it using `$item->overdue_status` like before

Comment: Yes but how to change to 'true'?

Comment: The accessor approach will lead to terrible performance issues, ie. when displaying a list view and you navigate back and forth it runs for every single record. i reccomend to use CRON, jobs and queue.